# Unable to run "Protractor test scripts in Firefox browser" for "angular 4 applicaiton"

Tags: angular, jasmine, webdriver, protractor

I am new to Protractor tool. I am unable to run my Test script in multiple browsers, only in Chrome.

I am using

1. Node: v6.11.3
2. NPM: 3.10.10
3. Protractor: 5.1.2

I need to automate the Angular 4 application using Visual studio code IDE. I added "multi capabilities" option my Protractor.conf.js as below.

```
multiCapabilities:[{
  'browserName' : 'chrome'},
  {'browserName':'firefox'}]
```

Test script was running in only chrome browser, For firefox it is displaying below error

```
[11:47:37] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[11:47:37] I/launcher - firefox #01 failed with exit code: 135
[11:47:37] I/launcher - chrome #11 passed
[11:47:37] I/launcher - overall: 1 process(es) failed to complete
[11:47:37] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

How to setup and run test scripts parallel in multiple browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firefox v48 and above, you'll also need to add marionette capability:

```
multiCapabilities:[
  {'browserName' : 'chrome'},
  {'browserName':'firefox',
   'marionette': true}]
```

UPDATE:
There is a [open issue #4253](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4253) introduced in Protractor 5.1.1 . The workaround is to manually replace `directConnect` with `seleniumAddress` and manually start `webdriver-manager` as specified in the bug:

> The solution is to use selenium standalone when testing with Firefox.
>   The latest version of the selenium standalone server is compatible
>   with Protractor's selenium JS bindings and with geckodriver. You can
>   update and launch the standalone server with
>
> ```
> webdriver-manager update
> webdriver-manager start
> ```
>
> and set `seleniumAddress: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I tried with 'marionette' option it is not working for me , still the same error is displaying

Comment: Sorry about that. There was bug introduced in protractor 5.1.1 that I had mistakenly thought was fixed. I've edited my answer with the workaround.

Comment: I followed the above update , now it is displaying  "Unable to parse new session response"  error message . Process exited with error code 199 .

I installed gecko driver and added that to the System - PATH variable.

Comment: test script is running now in "fire fox" when i change the seleniumAddress : http://localhost:4444 to seleniumAddress : http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

Comment: Great! I've edited the seleniumAddress value as you noted. Could you do me a favor and accept my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of several reasons for your error. Here some suggestions:

By default Protractor only updates Chrome driver. So please try `webdriver-manager update` [as described here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5820).

If that did not do the trick, check if your firefox-driver is at its expected location. [Read more about here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/886)

If you still have no luck, you might have catched an incompatibility between the current Firefox Driver and the latest Firefox-Browser (i.e. if you beta-test new firefox browser-version). [Read about the same issue for Chrome here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2176). It will work the same way for Firefox, of course.